# Classe protected e public

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos

Qual é o comportamento de uma classe protected?

Qual é o impacto dos modificadores de acesso (especialmente private e protected) nas classes, e quais suas comuns utilizações?

Consigo entender suas funcionalidades quando atribuídas a métodos, propriedades e atributos, mas não consigo enxergar o mesmo quando se trata de uma classe ou interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma classe "top-level" (definida diretamente no namespace) não pode ser `protected` - é um erro de compilação. Você só pode definir classes `protected` se elas forem definidas dentro de outras classes (como *nested classes*). O que o modificador faz é que somente a própria classe dentro da qual a sua *nested class* está definida, ou suas subclasses, podem acessar a sua classe protegida.

Por exemplo:

```
protected class A { } // não compila - erro

public class B {
    protected class C { }
    private void Metodo1() {
        // Funciona
        var c = new C();
        Console.WriteLine(c);
    }
}

public class D {
    private void Metodo2() {
        var c = new C(); // não compila - erro
        Console.WriteLine(c);
    }
}

public class E : B {
    private void Metodo3() {
        // Funciona
        var c = new B.C();
        Console.WriteLine(c);
    }
}
```